# Can you define a conditional format range without an absolute reference?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I would like to conditionally format a column in my sheet, regardless of how long the sheet is.  This is because new rows are routinely inserted, and the sheet gets longer but the conditional formatting doesn't adjust since it only uses absolute references.

To illustrate, for my range in the conditional format if I put in `A:A` I end up with `A1:A536` (or however long my sheet is at the moment I define the range).  If I add rows, it stays as `A1:A536`.  I would like to be able to define the conditional range as simply `A:A` but this doesn't work.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JVC, your conditional formatting rule should be adjusting when you add rows, if the previous version went to the last row (either expressly or as A:A). If you'd like to share a link to your sheet (or a copy of it, or a representative sample from it with the CF in place), being sure to set the Share permission to "Anyone with the link can edit," we can take a further look.

However, you an also try using INDIRECT("A:A") as the reference in the CF.

Comment: Oh wow look at that, so it does.  I just saw the explicit references and assumed they would not change as the sheet grew.  Hadn't actually tested it though... thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Glad to know I could point you to a simple solution for this one.